# How to show a blob image on HTML page in Django?

Tags: python, django, base64, blob

I have a image in the blob field in my mysql database. The images are displayed correctly using the base clients, but I can't display the image in html page.

I try to use base64 converter for returned bytes.

models.py:

```
class BlobImg(models.Model):
    photo = models.TextField(null=True)
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    obj = BlobImg.objects.get(id=1)
    image_data = base64.b64encode(obj.photo)

    data = {
        'news': News.objects.all(),
        'title': 'Главная страница',
        'imgs' : image_data
    }
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', data)
```

html:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ imgs }}" class="img-thumbnail">
```

I get bytes string in "imgs", but it doesn't work

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: please show the value.

Comment: Its a very long bytes value, how i can insert it in message?

Comment: `obj.photo`  value start with: b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\... etc.
`image_data` value start with:
b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQND... etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 the `base64.b64encode()` function returns encoded bytes, not a string. Because of this, your data URI is displayed as `data:image/jpeg;base64,b'/9j/4AA...'`, while it must be `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA...`. To fix this, decode bytes to string, for example using `base64.b64encode(obj.photo).decode()`.

Comment: I managed to apply it to a single object. Can I apply it in any way for query set like as `objects.all()` and send it in json?

Comment: @СергейМельник Sure. You need to apply the `base64.b64encode(obj.photo).decode()` to each object.